# unable to get row of comments from sqlite database index out of bounds

Tags: android, sqlite

Im trying to set an account activity to display as a result of an onItemClick and am storing the account information in a SQLite database that I am hoping to have displayed according to the respective Account name clicked in the listview.  However, When I try to select a row from the database, iterate through it, and return it as an ArrayList I get an error I think pretty much saying no Arraylist was created.  I cant seem to find the problem.

Here is the Data Access Object Class where I created the getRow() method which is where the problem lies I believe.

```
`package com.example.hardwoodassistant;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import com.example.hardwoodassistant.Comment;
import com.example.hardwoodassistant.MySQLiteHelper;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;

public class CommentsDataSource {

// Database fields
  private static SQLiteDatabase database;
  private MySQLiteHelper db;
  private String[] allColumns = { MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_ID,
      MySQLiteHelper.KEY_NAME, MySQLiteHelper.KEY_STREET, MySQLiteHelper.KEY_CITY,  
      MySQLiteHelper.KEY_PHONE, MySQLiteHelper.KEY_EMAIL};

  public  CommentsDataSource(Context ctx) {
      db = MySQLiteHelper.getInstance(ctx);
  }

  public void open() throws SQLException {
      database = db.getWritableDatabase();
  }

  public void close() {
      db.close();
  }

  public Comment createComment(String name, String _name, String street, String _street, String city, String _city,
          String phone, String _phone, String email, String _email) {
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(name, _name);
    values.put(street, _street);
    values.put(city, _city);
    values.put(phone, _phone);
    values.put(email, _email);

    long insertId = database.insert(MySQLiteHelper.TABLE_COMMENTS, null,
        values);
    Cursor cursor = database.query(MySQLiteHelper.TABLE_COMMENTS, new String[] {MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_ID, name},
        MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_ID + " = " + insertId, null,
        null, null, null, null);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    Comment newComment = cursorToComment(cursor);
    cursor.close();
    return newComment;
  }

  public void deleteComment(Comment comment) {
    long id = comment.getId();
    System.out.println("Comment deleted with id: " + id);
    database.delete(MySQLiteHelper.TABLE_COMMENTS, MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_ID
        + " = " + id, null);
  }

  public List<Comment> getAllComments() {
        List<Comment> comments = new ArrayList<Comment>();

        Cursor cursor = database.query(MySQLiteHelper.TABLE_COMMENTS,
            allColumns, null, null, null, null, null);

        cursor.moveToFirst();
        while (!cursor.isAfterLast()) {
          Comment comment = cursorToComment(cursor);
          comments.add(comment);
          cursor.moveToNext();
        }
        // make sure to close the cursor
        cursor.close();
        return comments;
      }

  public List<Comment> getNames()   {
      List<Comment> names = new ArrayList<Comment>();
      Cursor cursor = database.query(MySQLiteHelper.TABLE_COMMENTS, new String[] {MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_ID, MySQLiteHelper.KEY_NAME}, 
              null, null, null, null, null);
      cursor.moveToFirst();
        while (!cursor.isAfterLast()) {
          Comment comment = cursorToComment(cursor);
          names.add(comment);
          cursor.moveToNext();
        }

      cursor.close();
      return names;
  }

  public List<Comment> getRow(int id)   {
      List<Comment> row = new ArrayList<Comment>();
      Cursor cursor = database.query(MySQLiteHelper.TABLE_COMMENTS, new String[] {MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_ID, 
              MySQLiteHelper.KEY_NAME, MySQLiteHelper.KEY_STREET, MySQLiteHelper.KEY_CITY, MySQLiteHelper.KEY_PHONE, 
              MySQLiteHelper.KEY_EMAIL}, MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_ID + " =" + (id-1),null,null,null, null );

      while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
          Comment comment = cursorToComment(cursor);
          row.add(comment);
      }

      cursor.close();

      return row;
      }




  private Comment cursorToComment(Cursor cursor) {
        Comment comment = new Comment();
        comment.setId(cursor.getLong(0));
        comment.setComment(cursor.getString(1));
        return comment;
        }
}`
```

This is the account activity displaying the individual account information.

```
package com.example.hardwoodassistant;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Customer_account extends Activity {
private CommentsDataSource datasource;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.customer_details);

    datasource = new CommentsDataSource(this);
    datasource.open();

    TextView name = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    TextView address = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
    TextView phone = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView3);
    TextView email = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView4);

    int position = getIntent().getExtras().getInt("position");

    name.setText(datasource.getRow(position).get(0).toString());
    address.setText(datasource.getRow(position).get(1).toString() + " " + datasource.getRow(position).get(2).toString());
    phone.setText(datasource.getRow(position).get(3).toString());
    email.setText(datasource.getRow(position).get(4).toString());

    }

}
```

And this is the listactivity displaying the accounts to onitemclick.

```
package com.example.hardwoodassistant;

import java.util.List;


import com.example.hardwoodassistant.Comment;
import com.example.hardwoodassistant.R;


import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
public class Customer_Home extends ListActivity {
private CommentsDataSource datasource;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.customer_home);

    ListView lv = getListView();

    datasource = new CommentsDataSource(this);
    datasource.open();

    List<Comment> names = datasource.getNames();

    ArrayAdapter<Comment> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Comment>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, names);

    setListAdapter(adapter);

}

public void onClick(View view) {
    switch(view.getId())    {
        case R.id.add: 
            Intent toBidInfo = new Intent(Customer_Home.this, Bid_customerinfo.class);
            toBidInfo.putExtra("isFromAccounts", true);
            startActivity(toBidInfo);

    }
}

@Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);

    Intent intent = new Intent(Customer_Home.this, Customer_account.class);
    intent.putExtra("position", position);

    startActivity(intent);
}

@Override
  protected void onResume() {
    datasource.open();
    super.onResume();
  }

  @Override
  protected void onPause() {
    datasource.close();
    super.onPause();
  }

  @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.home, menu);
        return true;
    }
```

}

here is the logcat

```
    11-14 10:41:57.136: E/AndroidRuntime(9457):     at        android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2246)
11-14 10:41:57.136: E/AndroidRuntime(9457):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2296)
11-14 10:41:57.136: E/AndroidRuntime(9457):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:151)
11-14 10:41:57.136: E/AndroidRuntime(9457):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1281)
11-14 10:41:57.136: E/AndroidRuntime(9457):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
11-14 10:41:57.136: E/AndroidRuntime(9457):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
11-14 10:41:57.136: E/AndroidRuntime(9457):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5293)
11-14 10:41:57.136: E/AndroidRuntime(9457):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-14 10:41:57.136: E/AndroidRuntime(9457):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
11-14 10:41:57.136: E/AndroidRuntime(9457):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1102)
11-14 10:41:57.136: E/AndroidRuntime(9457):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:869)
11-14 10:41:57.136: E/AndroidRuntime(9457):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-14 10:41:57.136: E/AndroidRuntime(9457): Caused by: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 0, size is 0
11-14 10:41:57.136: E/AndroidRuntime(9457):     at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:251)
11-14 10:41:57.136: E/AndroidRuntime(9457):     at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:304)
11-14 10:41:57.136: E/AndroidRuntime(9457):     at com.example.hardwoodassistant.Customer_account.onCreate(Customer_account.java:26)
11-14 10:41:57.136: E/AndroidRuntime(9457):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5250)
11-14 10:41:57.136: E/AndroidRuntime(9457):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1097)
11-14 10:41:57.136: E/AndroidRuntime(9457):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2210)
```

Edit: Sorry there are a few other activities invloved I was trying to keep it brief but here is the activity where I create comments for the database.

```
package com.example.hardwoodassistant;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Bid_verify extends Activity {
private CommentsDataSource datasource;
//boolean isFromAccounts = getIntent().getExtras().getBoolean("isFromAccounts");

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.bid_verify);

    datasource = new CommentsDataSource(this);
    datasource.open();

    final ArrayList<Account> accounts = new ArrayList<Account>();

    TextView name = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    TextView street = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TextView01);
    TextView city = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TextView02);
    TextView phone = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TextView04);
    TextView email = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TextView03);

    name.setText(getIntent().getExtras().getString("name"));
    street.setText(getIntent().getExtras().getString("street"));
    city.setText(getIntent().getExtras().getString("city"));
    phone.setText(getIntent().getExtras().getString("phone"));
    email.setText(getIntent().getExtras().getString("email"));

    System.out.println(name.getText());

    Button next = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button5);


    next.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {


            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //if (isFromAccounts)   {

                Comment comment = null;

                accounts.add(new Account(getIntent().getExtras().getString("name"),
                        getIntent().getExtras().getString("street"), 
                        getIntent().getExtras().getString("city"), 
                        getIntent().getExtras().getString("phone"),
                        getIntent().getExtras().getString("email")));
                System.out.println(accounts.size());

                datasource.createComment("name", getIntent().
                        getExtras().getString("name"), "street", getIntent().
                        getExtras().getString("street"), "city", getIntent().
                        getExtras().getString("city"), "phone", getIntent().
                        getExtras().getString("phone"), "email", getIntent().
                        getExtras().getString("email"));



                Intent toAccounts = new Intent(Bid_verify.this, Customer_account.class);
                startActivity(toAccounts);
                }

                //else  {
                      //startActivity(new Intent(Bid_verify.this, Bid_jobtype.class));
                    //}
            });

        }       

@Override
  protected void onResume() {
    datasource.open();
    super.onResume();
  }

  @Override
  protected void onPause() {
    datasource.close();
    super.onPause();
  }
```

}

SQLiteHelper class

```
package com.example.hardwoodassistant;

import android.content.Context;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.util.Log;


public final class MySQLiteHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

private static MySQLiteHelper sInstance = null;

public static final String TABLE_COMMENTS = "comments";
public static final String COLUMN_ID = "_id";
public static final String KEY_NAME = "name";
public static final String KEY_STREET = "street";
public static final String KEY_CITY = "city";
public static final String KEY_PHONE = "phone";
public static final String KEY_EMAIL = "email";

public static final String COLUMN_COMMENT = "comment";

private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "comments.db";
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

private static final String DATABASE_CREATE = "create table "
          + TABLE_COMMENTS + "(" + COLUMN_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," + KEY_NAME
          + " TEXT," + KEY_STREET + " TEXT," + KEY_CITY + " TEXT," + KEY_PHONE + " TEXT," 
          + KEY_EMAIL + " TEXT" + ")";



private MySQLiteHelper(Context ctx) {
    super(ctx, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);

}

public static MySQLiteHelper getInstance(Context ctx) {
    if(sInstance == null)   {
        sInstance = new MySQLiteHelper(ctx.getApplicationContext());
    }
        return sInstance;

}

public static String getName()  {
    return DATABASE_NAME;
}

@Override
  public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase database) {
    if(database == null);
    database.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE);
}

@Override
  public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    Log.w(MySQLiteHelper.class.getName(),
        "Upgrading database from version " + oldVersion + " to "
            + newVersion + ", which will destroy all old data");
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_COMMENTS);
    onCreate(db);
}
```

}

Comment: Where do you create comments? You are just opening the database and trying to access an arraylist

Comment: Sorry I left out the activity where I create comments for brevity. See Edit. Thanks for the reply

Comment: Have you verified after the createComment that the datasource create's the Comments?

Comment: Yes. I actually have my list view display only the names from the database then when I click the names it should go to the next activity and display the rest of the particular account info but I think there has to be something wrong with my query or something in getRow() method.

Comment: *The listview displays the KEY_NAME column through an adapter so I know the database is being set (at least the KEY_NAME column values). I'll upload the SQLhelper class real quick if that helps too.

Comment: After the getRow does the query, does the cursor go into the while loop?

Comment: I believe so I input it as a parameter into the cursorToComment(cursor) method

Answer (score 0):

My first answer was not very helpful. So I try it again. I assume that the problem arises from this line:

```
name.setText(datasource.getRow(position).get(0).toString());
```

This would indicate that the problem that you have (IndexOutOfBound because your list is empty) is because the method getRow(position) returns an empty list.

When I look at this line I would say that you query a row that does not exist.

```
 Cursor cursor = database.query(MySQLiteHelper.TABLE_COMMENTS, new String[] {MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_ID, 
              MySQLiteHelper.KEY_NAME, MySQLiteHelper.KEY_STREET, MySQLiteHelper.KEY_CITY, MySQLiteHelper.KEY_PHONE, 
              MySQLiteHelper.KEY_EMAIL}, MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_ID + " =" + (id-1),null,null,null, null );
```

So check if your cursor is empty by calling cursor.getCount(). If this is zero then your cursor is empty.

EDIT: Did edit the whole answer to make my point clear and remove a false assumption.

EDIT 2: I think I know now what you want to achieve. Try this instead of your code:

```
public List<String> getRow(int id)   {
      List<String> row = new ArrayList<String>();
      Cursor cursor = database.query(MySQLiteHelper.TABLE_COMMENTS, new String[] {MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_ID, 
              MySQLiteHelper.KEY_NAME, MySQLiteHelper.KEY_STREET, MySQLiteHelper.KEY_CITY, MySQLiteHelper.KEY_PHONE, 
              MySQLiteHelper.KEY_EMAIL}, MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_ID + " =" + (id-1),null,null,null, null );

      while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
          //Get columns from cursor
          String name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MySQLiteHelper.KEY_NAME));
          String street = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MySQLiteHelper.KEY_STREET));
          String city = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MySQLiteHelper.KEY_CITY));
          String phone = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MySQLiteHelper.KEY_PHONE));
          String email = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnindex(MySQLiteHelper.KEY_EMAIL));
          //add columns to row list
          row.add(name);
          row.add(address);
          row.add(city);
          row.add(phone);
          row.add(email);
      }

      cursor.close();

      return row;
 }
```

But this does only work if your cursor is not empty!

Comment: I think this is close but ive found that it does create the row list however it only adds one category (KEY_NAME) in the cursor iterator not sure why the other column categories wont add to the row list. any clue?

Comment: I think it may have to do with movetonext() because my cursor is a row of 6 columns including _id but movetonext() is supposedly for rows i guess? I guess whats happening is I dont quite understand the cursor iterator methods if I have a row of account information i need to set to a row list for retrieval.

Comment: The cursor is holding the rows you selected with your query. In your case this is the row with column_id=(id-1). If you now want to select a column in this row you can do this by calling: cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("your_column_name"))

Comment: So in your case if you want to get for example the Key_Street in you can do: cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MySQLiteHelper.KEY_STREET));

Comment: I spoke too soon I just found that the problem is in my createcomment method. I am only creating a name column and all other information does not get created in the database. so when i call cursor.getCount(0 after the iterator it returns 1.  Guess i have to figure out createcomment's problems first.

Comment: Ok it seems that everything should get created in the insert() method in createcomment.  Any ideas?

Comment: Take care. I think your mixing up rows and columns. A column in the database consists all values of one label for example all values with the label KEY_STREET. A row consist ONE line with all values from labels COLUMN_ID, KEY_NAME, KEY_STREET, etc. So with your given query cursor.getCount() will ALWAYS return 0 or 1 because COLUMN_ID is the primary key and thus unique. See my updated answer!

Comment: I tried that before and it led me to the discovery that the problem lies in my database creation.  For some reason only the name category gets created. Sorry for the hassle.

Comment: I see know where you have your code from. Are you aware about all the methods you call and what they exactly do (for example the cursorToComment method)? I think you have to start with a smaller example. For example store data in your database which you know exactly and then try to get it back. This is just too big and has too many traps. A good start is the documentation http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/Cursor.html

Comment: Yes I think I understand the methods.  The cursorToComment method is a way of materializing the information stored in the database.  The way I see it is the comments class is how the cursor query turns into data that can be used by the application.  I haven't looked at the code since the other day but looking again I immediately notice when I add to my newComments arraylist I am only adding the name column . I was doing this for testing and forgot to change it back.  I think adding the other column categories here should fix my issues.  Anyways thank you for your help.

Comment: Edit: What I mean is the Comments class itself is unnecessary technically, but making the database information into objects themselves (in this case the author calls them comments, however, I should change the class name to contactData so it relates to this particular table) allows for easy access and manipulation of the data. This is how I understand it. What I am more curious about is the cursor.query method. Specifically if you create multiple content values it should insert all the information in the corresponding keys even if it is more than one key/value pair right?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is correct but for insert() and not for query(). And yes the problem is that you are adding just the name column with getString(1) and the id with getLong(0) . It is better to retrieve the columIndex by getColumnIndex(columnName) (see my answer) so this will not break if you change the order of the retrieved column in query(). And you see better what you are doing. If you have more questions to other things then ask them in a new question thread. Have fun!